# SimpleXML object reading in PHP

Tags: php, xml

In `$val` I am getting this value `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 464)`. How do i put value at `[0]` i.e `464` in $ a. I tried using foreach but its not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try reading the manual or post the XML ..

Comment: Pretty damn vague. Post your XML + the PHP you are using to try to read it. It will be pretty hard for people to help otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo>464</foo>');
$a = (int)$doc; // or (string)
print_r($doc);
print_r($a);
```

prints

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 464
)
464
```